# Puzzled: Responsive header with special resizing through pure HTML/CSS?

Tags: responsive-design, fluid-layout, css

We have a solution utilizing JavaScript, but I'm also curious if there is a way to do this with pure CSS?

## The Situation

I'm relatively new to responsive design, and in the past have stuck with positioning, etc to achieve my layouts.  I'm attempting to create a simple responsive header that resizes in a specific way.

## My Dilemma

The header is a 29px high bar at the top of the page, with 29x29 buttons at either end.  In the middle, bordering the button on the right, is a div (for page titles) that I want to have a min width of 300, but I also want it to expand with the browser width.

*Here is the catch:* I want this title div to pull away from the left button, leaving a gap of a *max-width* of 200px. Once the max-width of the gap is reached, I would like the title div to start expanding, staying pressed up against the right button. See as follows.

[image: IMG]

*note: I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vRr3Z/) for experimenting*

Comment: I think my main problem with this is that I'm not actually sure if it's even possible to do with just CSS/HTML. Advice on this would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [modified your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRr3Z/2/) and added a bit of JavaScript to get the effect I think you're looking for. There are also comments to walk you through exactly what the JS code is trying to accomplish.

Essentially, I'm binding a handler to the window.resize event, calculating the available space in the header, and adding or subtracting from the title container to maintain its width.

Comment: Great, thank you Daniel.  I added min-width to the JSFiddle you posted and updated the link in your answer for the sake of completeness.  I presume this is also confirmation that this is not possible without JavaScript?

Comment: I'm sometimes overkeen and occasionally tend to use JavaScript as a fix-all, but I can't think off the top of my head of a combination of `min-width` and `max-width` and widths set to `auto` or similar that'd generate the effect without JS. I'd certainly be interested to see this working without it.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to use pure CSS, but am also in the middle of a project. I have edited the question to try and get a CSS answer, but this is still extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Okay well here is what I have so far. WILL EDIT in the morning (kind of tired)

I feel this is definitely possible but it does require javascript. The fact that you want there to be a 200px space available requires javascript or some sort of programming to tell the styling to do that.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        html, body { height: 100%; }
        #container { margin-top: 29px; }
        header { height:29px; margin: 0 49px; background-color:#999999; }

        #div1 { width: 29px; height: 100%; background-color: yellow; display: inline-block; }
        #div2 { width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; display: inline-block; }
        #div3 { width: 29px; height: 100%; background-color: red; display: inline-block; float: right;}
        #div4 { height: 100%; background-color: yellow; display: inline-block;  float: right; }
    </style>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <div id="div1">div1</div><div id="div2">div2</div><div id="div3">div3</div><div id="div4">div4</div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
    <script>
        if (parseInt(document.getElementById("div2").clientWidth) >= 200) {
            document.getElementById("div2").style.width = "200px";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

So the way I went about it is rather than having 3 divs, I made 4 -- the original 3 you had, but then the white space you want to consider as, well open space, I made a div for that as well. I also have javascript so that when the window scales past a width of 200px, it will lock it at that width. Unfortunately, I'm not super polished with my CSS yet so I'm still trying to figure a way to get that working. If anyone wants to edit my answer, please feel free.

Another thing to point out is that while the javascript does working for if the nav is growing, it doesn't for shrinking. I didn't implement a way for it to be able to shrink if say the user decided to shrink his window size because I have it set to lock the width at 200px (I guess a way to work around that would be with an `} else { clientWidth = "100%"`? Not sure. Hope this gets you on the right track though.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and the snippet.  I've awarded the answer to Daniel above as it is quite complete, but I do appreciate your answer as well. Upvoted for usefulness.

Comment: No worries I'm glad you found your answer :] I feel a lot of people would have this question.

Comment: I am still wondering if it is somehow possible to do this with just HTML/CSS though. :-)

Comment: hmmm I might look into it. I thought your answer was solved already but if you want I can play around with it later today. I'll update my answer and comment here when I do